# Does Sklar's Theorem work when $P(X_k \leq t)$ are not continuous?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, copula

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)) here describes for $X = (X_1,...,X_n): \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ with each $F_k(t) = P(X_k \leq t)$ continuous, there is a pushforward measure induced on $[0,1]^n$ via $(F_1(X_1),...,F_n(X_n))$. Using this measure, one finds $Y(u_1,...,u_n)=(F_1^{-1}(u_1),...,F_n^{-1}(u_n)), \ \forall (u_1,...,u_n) \in [0,1]^n$, has the same distribution as $X$.

When Sklar's theorem is described, it appears that it is no longer assuming each marginal $F_k$ is continuous. This makes me wonder why they assumed it in the first place.

Does Sklar's theorem or a related theorem imply for $(X_1,...,X_n)$ (where the $F_k$ are not continuous) there exists a nice measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]^n$ and $Y: [0,1]^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, $Y(s_1,...,s_n) = (Y_1(s_1),....,Y_n(s_n))$, with the same distribution as $X$?

Answer (score 3):

Copulas exist whether the marginals of $\mathbf{X}=[X_1,\ldots,X_n]^\intercal$ are continuous or not. The issue is that for noncontinuous the copula is not unique in general, and different choices may introduce artificial local dependence between the components of a random vector.

Constructions of copulas can be obtained by an extension of the "quantile transform" as follows:

- Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space,
- Suppose $X$ is a real-valued random on $\Omega$, and let $F(x):=\mathbb{P}[X\leq x]$.
- The distributional transform of $X$ is the function $G:\mathbb{R}\times[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined as
  $$G(x,v)=F(x-)+v(F(x)-F(x-))$$
- Let $V\sim\operatorname{Unif}(0,1)$ independent from $X$ and define the random variable
  $$U:=G(X,V).$$
  It can be shown that

1. $U\sim\operatorname{Unif}(0,1)$, and
2. that $X=Q(U)$ $\mathbb{P}$-a.s., where $Q$ is the quantile transform of $X$, that is $Q(t)=\inf\{x\in\mathbb{R}: F(x)\geq t\}$.
3. Recall that $F(x)\leq t$ iff $Q(t)\leq x$.
4. From (3)  it follows that if $F$ is continuous at $Q(t)$, then $F(Q(t))=t$. Hence, when $F$ is contuinuous,  then $U=F(X)\sim\operatorname{Unif}(0,1)$ which is a well known fact for continuous random variables.

> Theorem:  Suppose $\mathbf{X}=[X_1,\ldots ,X_n]^\intercal$ is an $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued random variable with distribution $F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\mathbb{P}[X_1\leq x_1,]\ldots,X_n\leq x_n]$. Denote by $F_j(x)=\mathbb{P}[X_j\leq x]$ the marginal distribution of the $j$-th component of $\mathbf{X}$. There exists a measure $\nu$ on $([0,1]^n,\mathscr{B}([0,1]^n))$ with $U(0,1)$-marginals such that
> \begin{align}
>     F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=C(F_1(x_1),\ldots, F_n(x_n))\label{copula1}
>   \end{align}
> where $C(u_1,\ldots,u_n)=\nu([0,u_1]\times\ldots\times[0,u_n])$. The function $C$ is said to be a ***copula*** for $\mathbf{X}$ (or for the distribution $F$).

*Proof:* Here is a short proof based on the extended quantile transform introduced above. Let $V\sim U(0,1)$ independent from $\mathbf{X}=[X_1,\ldots, X_n]$, and for each $1\leq j\leq n$  define
$$U_j=F_j(X_j-)+\big(F_j(X_j)-F_j(X_j-)\big)V$$
where $F_j$ is the distribution function of $X_j$. Let $Q_j$ be the quantile function associated to $X_j$. Observations (1) and (2) above imply that  $U_j\sim U(0,1)$ and that $Q_j(U_j)=X_j$ a.s. Let $C$ be the joint distribution of $\mathbf{U}=[U_1,\ldots, U_n]^\intercal$, that is
$$
C(u_1,\ldots,u_n)=\mathbb{P}[U_1\leq u_1,\ldots, U_n\leq u_n).
$$
It follows that
\begin{align}
  \mathbb{P}[X_j\leq x_j,1\leq j\leq n]&=\mathbb{P}[Q_j(U_j)\leq x_j,1\leq j\leq n]\\
  &=\mathbb{P}[U_j\leq F(x_j), \,1\leq j\leq n]=C(F(x_1),\ldots, F(x_n))
\end{align}

---

Comments:

- If each marginal $X_i$ is continuous, then $C$ is unique as $C$ is the distribution of $[F_1(X_1),\ldots, F_n(X_n)]^\intercal$.
- If $\mathbf{X}$ is not continuous, different choices of the randomizations V at the jumps or in the components, i.e. choosing $U_i = G_i(X_i , V_i)$ give different copulas.
- In this case, from a given a choice of a copula  is not possible to see whether some local positive or negative dependence is a real one or just comes from the particular choice of the copula.
- The distributional  transform function $G(x,v)$ goes back to Ferguson, T. S.,  Mathematical Statistics: A Decision Theoretic Approach. Probability and Mathematical Statistics, Vol. 1. New York: Academic Press, 1967.
- The idea to use the distributional transform $G$ to prove Sklar's theorem appears also in Rüschendorf, L.,On the distributional transform, Sklar’s Theorem, and the empirical copula process., Journal of Statistical Planning and Inference,  Volume 139, Issue 11, 1 November 2009, Pages 3921-3927

Comment: The copula $C$ is not a measure is it? $C(F_1(x_1),...,F_n(x_n))$ is $C$ applied to a single point in $[0,1]^n$. If $C$ were a measure this would imply it is giving mass to points in $[0,1]^n$, rather than the sets $[0,F_1(x_1)] \times \cdots \times [0, F_n(x_n)]$.

Comment: @StephenHarrison: $C$ is the multidimensional distribution of the random vector $[U_1,\ldots,U_n]^\intercal$, that is, $C(u_1,\ldots,u_n)=P[U_1\leq u_1,\ldots,U_n\leq u_n]$ for $0\leq u_1,\dots, u_n\leq1$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Sklar's theorem holds for all distributions.

For every multivariate cumulative distribution function (cdf), there exits a **copula** with cdf $C: [0,1]^n \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that:

$$F(x_1,...,x_n)=C \left (F_{X_1}(x_1),..., F_{X_n}(x_n) \right).$$

A copula is any multivariate distribution whose univariate margins are uniform distributions on $[0,1]$.

When, the margins have discrete distributions, it is not easy to find the underlying copula (while there is one); see Section 2 of this [paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/astin-bulletin-journal-of-the-iaa/article/primer-on-copulas-for-count-data/B1857CBA9F03491F6CD41B85A553E977). However, you can easily use **any copula** to construct a multivariate distribution with **arbitrary univariate margins.**